# Detect Image Page Load on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I can detect web page DOMContentLoaded event by assigning below event listener to gBrowser.

```
if (event.originalTarget instanceof HTMLDocument) {
    var doc = event.originalTarget;
    if (event.originalTarget.defaultView.frameElement) {
        while (doc.defaultView.frameElement) {
            return;
        }
    } 
}
```

But above code does not detect chrome pages which are used to wrap images.  Example:

https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/app-icons/med/firefox.png

How can the document which is loading images be detected for Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the image is hosted by an `ImageDocument`. Append your if condition accordingly.